# Perfect and Complete trees for a general tree. (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

```
data BTree a = Nil | Node a (BTree a) (BTree a) deriving Show
```

I learned about two binary search trees. One is perfect the other one is complete.

A Binary tree is Perfect Binary Tree in which all internal nodes have two children and all leaves are at same level.

A Binary Tree is complete Binary Tree if all levels are completely filled except possibly the last level and the last level has all keys as left as possible

```
isPerfect :: BTree a -> Bool
isPerfect Nil = True
isPerfect (Node x Nil Nil) = True
isPerfect (Node x lt Nil ) = False
isPerfect (Node x Nil rt ) = False
isPerfect (Node x lt  rt ) = (&&) (isPerfect lt) (isPerfect rt)


isComplete :: BTree a -> Bool
isComplete Nil = True
isComplete (Node x Nil Nil) = True
isComplete (Node _ lt Nil ) = False
isComplete (Node x Nil rt ) = False
isComplete (Node _ (Node _ Nil Nil) Nil) = True
isComplete (Node x lt  rt ) = (&&) (isComplete lt) (isComplete rt)
```

Now I had to implement a data type for a general tree

```
data GTree a = Leaf a | Branch a [GTree a] deriving (Show)
```

How would I check if this tree is complete or perfect and would I have to change the definition?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `isPerfect` does not check if all leaves ar at the same level.

Comment: Duplicate of a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51800519/how-to-check-if-my-binary-search-tree-is-complete-haskell) which at the moment has no correct answer.

Comment: @chi, not a full duplicate, I don't think.

Comment: The only difference I see is that here we use general trees -- perhaps that's enough to make it different. (This question also starts from a wrong implementation of `isPerfect` and `isComplete`.)

Answer (score 0):

First, let's stick with binary trees.  Consider the following binary tree:

```
  1
 / \
2   3
   / \
  4   5
```

It can be represented as:

```
badTree = Node 1 (Node 2 Nil Nil) (Node 3 (Node 4 Nil Nil) (Node 5 Nil Nil))
```

This tree is neither perfect nor complete, but your functions say that it is:

```
> isPerfect badTree
True
> isComplete badTree
True
>
```

So, it looks like you still have some work to do.

Second, to generalize this to "general trees", yes, you will need to modify the definitions.  It would be reasonable to consider the subset of general trees where all leaves are at the same level (with no requirement on the number of children per node) or where all leaves are at the same level *and* each interior node has the same number of children (e.g., 2, or 3, or 4) or has at *least* two children or something else.  However, I'm not aware of a generally accepted definition for "perfect" or "complete" general trees, so you'd be making it up as you go along.

Third, it's maybe worth pointing out that your `GTree` implementation might not be ideal.  Usually a "leaf" is a node without children, but you have two ways of representing a node without children:

```
Leaf 10
Branch 10 []
```

Should these be the same tree?  If so, there ideally shouldn't be two different representations.